# gain value at intermediate knob positions?

Tags: audio-interfaces, gain

I study and record bat calls using consumer audio devices. I've been using the Fireface USB audio interface series (802, UC, UCX) along with their other 4 channel preamp devices.

The gain knob has 3 positions at which the [gain is defined](https://rme-audio.de/fireface-802.html) - 6, 30 and 60 dB, at around 7, 12 and 5 o'clock. See cropped knob image here:
[image]

I called customer support to ask for the gain values in between, but it didn't lead to any new info.

*Edit round2:* Here are my measurements (feeding a 50 mVpp, 50 kHz sinewave from an oscilloscope), the recorded audio level is reported in dB rms for each knob position). All angles are reported relative to the 6 dB starting position in clock-wise direction. **X-ticks are not to scale**

[image]

I know the gain values increase non-linearly based on this plot. The thing is that I've done a *lot* of recordings at intermediate positions, and am now wondering how to model this nonlinear change in knob gain.

As you can see from the plot, I don't really have a direct measurement of the gain to say if the 6 dB position is actually 6 dB, but I think it's safe to assume so.

Assuming so, my calculations tell me the gain at the knob positions are (see plot below).

[image]

However, does anyone have any ideas of what the typical trend of increase for such knobs is (square, exponential, log..etc?) - in relation to standard amp circuits or any kind of electronic designs?

```
Raw data for the plot
# degrees, 6dB position is 0 degrees
angles = [0, 36, 76, 112, 152, 192, 230, 268, 302] 
# calculated using relative gain with 6 dB position as reference.
measured_gain = [6, 7, 10, 21, 29, 35, 41, 46, 59] dB 
(Admittedly there might be a +/- 1 dB error in my measurements due to their manual nature.)
```

Comment: Just measure it. Shouldn't be a problem if you have the interface in your hands and you understand the math of decibels. Being able to make a custom attenuator (resistors, cable)  for comparison would be useful.

Comment: Hi @user287001, I have measured the gain at various positions, but would like to have a 'model' to compare with.

Comment: Publish the list of clock positions and measured gains. Then we may see (or not) which preamp gain control circuit fits. A good enough gain vs position formula also may be possible to generate without guessing anything of the circuit.

Comment: (continued) In modern high cost gear the gain can be controlled in the actual circuit digitally (=switching a resistor network). The knob can be an encoder. Clever timing of the changes prevent the zipper noise.

Comment: In a simple device, a logarithmic gain pot will give an apparent linear volume change.

Comment: You use unknown rotation angle units. How much as degrees is for ex is pos 2 as compared to "6" or to pos 3. I must admit I cannot see what this presents. Please use common clock values and only them. Or degrees measured from extreme CCW position.

Comment: valid points @user287001. Add angles, and a plot + raw data. Hope it clarifies the situation.

Comment: A commercial curve fitting website matched a cubic spline to your set of measured points and gave this curve for intermediate values::https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPmOQ.png Check if that site could help you. A customer could get the result as an Excel spreadsheet to be used offline. No idea here how useful the intermediate values are. In theory the fitted curve can be right, but as well it can be totally wrong because the fitting algorithm cannot know anything of your system. It only tries to find a smooth curve which exists in the selected  curve class. I selected class "cubic spline, natural".

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is not laboratory-grade equipment. The pots are probably not the best and you'll probably get different readings from each one. On top of that, you're positioning the pot by eye with no graded detents so you're bringing in subtle discrepancies every time you turn the pot. You are not going to get anything more precise than you already have.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at where the stated values fall compared to the dial positions, you can see something that approaches a straight line.

[image]

I couldn't find a sensible function that maps to this extremely shallow curve without using contorted mathematics or a ridiculous number of decimal places and exponents. I have to conclude from this that the values stated on the dial are not entirely accurate.

The '6' and the '60' might be accurate but the '30' is probably rounded from something less aesthetically pleasing.

For a perfectly straight line, each of the dial markings would indicate an increase of 6.75dB. This would mean that the '30' marker is actually '33'.

However, as this is not laboratory-grade equipment, I would suggest that the markings are a rough guide only and that you should use the meters in your software to dial in the values you want.